# Insert multiline text before the first matching line in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, logs, perl

we want to add the following lines in log4j file

```
log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize=10MB
```

but these lines must be before the first line that include the word - **DatePattern** , and no matter if line is with mark or not

```
#log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
```

or

```
log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
```

note - in case  DatePattern word apears couple times in file , then the three lines must be set only before the first line that include - DatePattern

example 1 ( expected output )

```
log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize=10MB


#log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
```

example 2  ( expected output )

```
log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize=10MB


log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you merely want to replace this line:

```
log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
-or-
#log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
```

With these lines:

```
log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
-or-
#log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
```

This GNU `sed` command can do this:

```
$ sed -i 's/\(.*appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.*\)/log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender\nlog4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=100\nlog4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize=10MB\n\n\n\1/' log4j.properties
```

With respect to the duplicating of lines. You're not going to have this appender defined more than 1 time:

```
appender.DRFA.DatePattern
```

Therefore we can look more explicitly for this occurrence, rather than the `DatePattern` line that you're looking for.

#### Example run

Here's a sample file that has just this line in it:

```
$ cat log4j.properties
#log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
```

Run the `sed` command above against this file:

```
$ cat log4j.properties
log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize=10MB
#log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
```

Comment: @yael -  I updated the answer so that it includes them now.

Answer (score 7):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'done != 1 && /DatePattern/ {
    print "log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"
    print "log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=100"
    print "log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize=10MB"
    done = 1
    } 1' file >newfile && mv newfile file
```

This would print the three lines when the first match of `DatePattern` occurs in the file.  The flag `done` is then set to `1` which stops the lines from being printed again.  The trailing `1` at the very end causes every line in the in-data to be printed.

If you want empty lines in the output after the three lines, add `\n\n` to the end of the last string.

The output is written to `newfile` and if `awk` did not encounter any strange errors, the original is then replaced by this once the `awk` process terminates.

---

Requested in comments: Adding the lines *after* the matched line,

```
awk '1; done != 1 && /DatePattern/ {
    print "log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"
    print "log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=100"
    print "log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize=10MB"
    done = 1
    }' file
```

This moves the `1` (which does the printing of each input line and could be replaced by `{ print }`) to before the code that is triggered when the pattern matches.

Comment: good solution , but I prefer to update the file itself like "sed -i" and not copy the file to the source file for update , is it possible with awk ?

Comment: @yael A standard redirection and `mv`. See updated answer. Not even GNU `awk` has an in-place editing option. It's not something that `awk` program usually do.

Comment: [`GNU awk` has it...](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html)

Comment: @don_crissti :-) That's an extension, even to GNU `awk`.

Comment: Sure but that doesn't change the fact that it exists... Anyway, +1 for answering the actual question here...

Comment: @Kusalananda can you please add another case when we want to add the three lines after the line with the word - DatePattern  instead before the word - DatePattern

Comment: @yael See updated answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda  excellent - well done , I am really appropriate it

Answer (score 4):

Using `GNU sed` you may approach it this way also:

```
sed -i -e '
    /DatePattern/!b

    i\
log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender\
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=100\
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize=10MB

    :a;n;$!ba
' input.file
```

And if you are sure that the `DatePattern` cannot be on the last line of the file, then you could do this also:

```
sed -i -e '
    /DatePattern/!b
    r file2add.txt
    N;:a;n;$!ba
' input.file
```

where you put all the lines to be added into a file, say `file2add.txt`. Note: with this method, you don't put trailing backslashes in the file `file2add.txt`.

Comment: Yes, those are both proper ways to do it with `sed`. Future visitors should keep in mind that `i` requires any embedded backslashes to be escaped.

Comment: And that the empty label and `;` concatenation are GNU extensions to sed.

Comment: @TobySpeight - empty label is specified by POSIX: _"`b [label]`  Branch to the `:` command verb bearing the label argument. If label is not specified, branch to the end of the script"_. Some commands can also be concatenated via `;` per the same standard: _"Editing commands other than `{...}`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `i`, `r`, `t`, `w`, `:`, and `#` can be followed by a <semicolon>, optional <blank> characters, and another editing command."_

Comment: Thanks for the correction (I note that `:` is among the commands that can't be joined with a subsequent command, so I turned out to be slightly correct by accident!)

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this query with `perl` also, so here goes one obvious way:

```
perl -pi -e '
     print <<\EOF if /DatePattern/ && !$seen++;
log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize=10MB
EOF
' input.file
```

Note: The added text mustn't contain the standalone string `EOF` on a line by itself. The backslashing of the heredoc is necessary , lest any variables get expanded .

If you cannot be sure of the above constraints in the text to add, then do this:

```
perl -pi -e '
    next if !/DatePattern/ || $seen++;
    open my $fh, "<", "file2add.txt" or die "Could not open file for reading:$!\n";
    $_ = join "", <$fh>, $_;
' input.file
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job well-suited to `ed`, the standard file editor:

```ed
/DatePattern/i
log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize=10MB
.
wq
```